# Deleting documents from Solr using UI?

Tags: solr

I want to delete some of the documents from Solr index. Searching google I found

```
update?stream.body=<delete><query>id:XXXXX</query></delete>&commit=true
```

but when I am coping it as

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/myIndex_shard1_replica1/http://10.101.3.240:8983/solr/#/solr_Ivision_DTO_shard1_replica1
```

I am getting error that the page does not exists.

Is there any other way from UI where I can delete the docs.

Thanks

Comment: `http://localhost:8983/solr/YOURCORE/update?stream.body=<delete><query>id:XXXXX</query></delete>&commit=true` 
The second URL is definitely wrong. Try something like this. Replace YOURCORE with the actual core name and  id:XXXXX with a valid query, or `*:*` for all docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting solr documents from Solr Admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228727/deleting-solr-documents-from-solr-admin)

Comment: I've just added an answer to the above mention duplicate question.  If it ever gets any votes, we can probably close this one, because that question will have an answer that has votes > 0.

Answer (score 7):

Now in 7.2 it's a bit different...to delete using the ui:

Go to the core's Documents page. eg: http://[your-host]:8983/solr/#/[your-core-name]/documents

Or

From the admin, select a core from the drop down at the bottom of the left side menu, then click 'Documents' from core menu

Then on the documents page

- Change Document Type to XML
- Enter the following XML into the Document(s) text box:

  `<delete><query>id:XXXXX</query></delete>`
- Click the Submit Document button

Answer (score 4):

```
 USE:
```

To delete all the document.

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/TABLE_NAME/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3E*:*%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E&commit=true
```

To delete specific document with given id:

```
 http://localhost:8983/solr/TABLE_NAME/update?stream.body=%3Cdelete%3E%3Cquery%3Eid:12%3C/query%3E%3C/delete%3E&commit=true
```

Answer (score 2):

You could delete documents in `Apache` `Solr` as below via UI. As preferred you could go ahead with either `JSON` or `XML`.

Steps:

1. Go to Solr Admin UI
2. Select a core from the drop down at the bottom of the left side menu
3. Click 'Documents' from core menu
4. Change Document Type to XML/ JSON
5. Enter the right Command below as selected above: i.e. XML/ JSON
6. Finally Click "Submit Document" button

**JSON**:

```
{'delete': {'query': '*:*'}}
```

**XML**:

```
<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
```

It will automatically `commit` your transaction hence no need to worry.

Answer (score 0):

To delete ALL documents with Solr 9.4.1 using the Web UI

Go to the Documents page of your core:
http://localhost:8983/solr/#/my_core_name/documents

Choose XML document type

Use this query: `<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>`